# Replace column value based on value in other column

Tags: python, pandas

so far my dataframe looks like this:

```
ID   Area   Stage
1    P      X
2    Q      X
3    P      X
4    Q      Y
```

I would like to replace the area 'Q' with 'P' for every row where the Stage is equal to 'X'.

So the result should look like:

```
ID   Area   Stage
1    P      X
2    P      X
3    P      X
4    Q      Y
```

I tried:

```
data.query('Stage in ["X"]')['Area']=data.query('Stage in ["X"]')['Area'].replace('Q','P')
```

It does not work. Help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Are you looking for a more dynamic answer where it checks for values in Area and Stage, Then replace all values in Area to the most occurring value in Stage?  My initial response was just to replace Q with P. However, I thought your request was for more generic and not specific to a particular value. Can you clarify please.

Comment: My question refers to a specific value. The answer of Quang Hoang does what I want it to do :)

Comment: Michelle I think @JoeFerndz ask you to clarify if *Area* can only value P or Q, because him and  RavinderSingh13 do that assumption in their answer

Comment: Ahh ok. Actually, for stage X, Area takes only the values P and Q. In general, there are also other Areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `loc` to specify where you want to replace, and pass the replaced series to the assignment:

```
df.loc[df['Stage']=='X', 'Area'] = df['Area'].replace('Q','P')
```

Output:

```
   ID Area Stage
0   1    P     X
1   2    P     X
2   3    P     X
3   4    Q     Y
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use 2 boolean conditions and use `loc`:

```
df.loc[df['Area'].eq("Q") & df['Stage'].eq('X'),'Area']='P'
print(df)
```

---

```
   ID Area Stage
0   1    P     X
1   2    P     X
2   3    P     X
3   4    Q     Y
```

Or `np.where`

```
df['Area'] = np.where(df['Area'].eq("Q") & df['Stage'].eq('X'),'P',df['Area'])
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 thank you, I think another condition should be added since `Stage==X` with `Area==Z` might also be replaced with `P` otherwise :-)

Comment: yeah, but not sure I kept it simple by keeping OP's question's summary :) OP can confirm it all cheers :)

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df['Area']=np.where(df['Stage']=='X','P',df['Area'])
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note : this not an answer proposing a new way to do, but a comparison of the execution time each needs**

All the proposals in the answers are quite 'magic' doing the job in one line of code thanks to pandas/numpy, anyway to do the job is good but to do it quickly is better, so I wanted to compare the execution time of each.

Here my program, in the loops I modify the dataframe two times to let it  unchanged from a turn to the next ( I am not a Python programmer as you so sorry in advance if the way to do is 'poor') :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

df=pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [i for i in range(1,1000)],
                 'Area' : ['P' if (i & 1) else 'Q' for i in range(1,1000)],
                 'Stage' : [ 'X' if (i & 2) else 'Y' for i in range(1,1000)]})

t0=time.process_time()
for i in range(1,100):
    df.loc[df['Stage']=='X', 'Area'] = df['Area'].replace('Q','q')
    df.loc[df['Stage']=='X', 'Area'] = df['Area'].replace('q','Q')

print("Quang Hoang", '%.2f' % (time.process_time() - t0))

t0=time.process_time()
for i in range(1,100):
    df.loc[df['Stage'] == 'X', 'Area'] = 'q'
    df.loc[df['Stage'] == 'X', 'Area'] = 'Q'

print("Joe Ferndz", '%.2f' % (time.process_time() - t0))

t0=time.process_time()
for i in range(1,100):
    df.loc[df['Area'].eq("Q") & df['Stage'].eq('X'),'Area']='q'
    df.loc[df['Area'].eq("q") & df['Stage'].eq('X'),'Area']='Q'

print("anky 1", '%.2f' % (time.process_time() - t0))

t0=time.process_time()
for i in range(1,100):
    df['Area'] = np.where(df['Area'].eq("Q") & df['Stage'].eq('X'),'q',df['Area'])
    df['Area'] = np.where(df['Area'].eq("q") & df['Stage'].eq('X'),'Q',df['Area'])

print("anky 2", '%.2f' % (time.process_time() - t0))

t0=time.process_time()
for i in range(1,100):
    df['Area']=np.where(df['Stage']=='X','q',df['Area'])
    df['Area']=np.where(df['Stage']=='X','Q',df['Area'])

print("RavinderSingh13", '%.2f' % (time.process_time() - t0))
```

On my PI 4 the result is :

```
Quang Hoang 1.60
Joe Ferndz 1.12
anky 1 1.55
anky 2 0.86
RavinderSingh13 0.38
```

if I use a dataframe having 100000 lines rather than 1000 the result is :

```
Quang Hoang 10.79
Joe Ferndz 6.61
anky 1 10.91
anky 2 9.64
RavinderSingh13 4.75
```

Note the proposals of Joe Ferndz and RavinderSingh13 suppose Area is only 'P' or 'Q'

Comment: this is so awesome. it clearly shows that numpy is the best option in this case. I thought .loc would be great but numpy beat it.

Answer (score 1):

To update a column using value from another column, use this option:

```
df.loc[df['Stage'] == 'X', 'Area'] = 'P'
```

This will check if value of `'Stage'` is `X`. If True, then it will replace value of `'Area'` to `'P'`

Comment: Dang. Yes. Sorry. Didnt realize the extra =